# Proportion of odd digits in powers of $2$ base ten

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $n \ge 1,$ if $2^n$ in base ten has $d$ digits, $k$ of which are odd, define $f(n)=k/d.$ I'm wondering whether $f(n)$ can get arbitrarily close to $1,$ or on the other hand does $f(n)$ have a least upper bound which is less than $1.$ [If the latter can we find that lub?]

We have  $f(9)=2/3,$ since $2^9=512.$ we can't have $f(n)=1$ since the units digit is even. I'd be interested in some specific cases where $f(n)$ is "fairly near" $1$ [whatever that means].

Comment: Worth noting:  problems like this tend not to be solvable.  See, for instance, the comparatively simpler [Conjecture of Erdos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33942/do-the-base-3-digits-of-2n-avoid-the-digit-2-infinitely-often-what-is-the) regarding the ternary expressions of powers of $2$.

Comment: I have computed $f(n)$ for $1\le n\le10^5$. Maximum is $f(76)=0.695652$. The mean is $0.499857$.

Comment: The number of odd digits in $2^n$ is the number of digits $\ge5$ in $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre a look at the larger numbers make it feels like when $n \rightarrow \infty$ it goes to $0$. look for $f(n)$ in $100<n<10^5$, and than $500<n<10^5$ and than $2000<n<10^5$.. Do you feel the same? EDIT: I use python on online compiler cause my computer sucks, I can look only up to n=1000..

Comment: The values cluster around $0.5$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, could you post this please at the linked question ? I then can delete this unlucky link.